# What is the Point of Barreling Charge?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, charge

There is a feat in Martial Power 2 called Barreling Charge:

> **Prerequisite:** Any martial class
>   **Benefit:** When you charge with a reach weapon, you can end your charge in the nearest square adjacent to the target of the charge.

Well, yeah, you can do that normally, can't you?

I don't see anything in the Rules Compendium anywhere to suggest that Reach stops you from charging all the way to your target. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for charge were originally written in the Player's Handbook and contained the following limitation to movement:

> You must move at least 2 squares from your starting position, and you must move directly to the nearest square from which you can attack the enemy.

With a reach weapon this meant that you must end a charge at the length of your reach, not in an adjacent square.

Martial Power 2 was then published with the barreling Charge feat, which did have some use to those with reach weapons based on the charge rules at the time.

The rules for charging were then rewritten in the official Player's Handbook errata to a version very similar to what later appeared in the Rules Compendium, but this new rule does not specify what happens when charging with a reach weapon (or any melee basic attack that has a greater range than melee 1), thus Barreling Charge is now redundant, since technically by RAW charge no longer specifies how close to the target you need to end your move when you have melee reach.

Comment: Even with that original wording, it did not occur to me that you were required to *stop* at the nearest square from which you can attack the enemy. Good catch.

Comment: @DCShannon, "the nearest square" from which you can attack is naturally one of the furthest squares from which you can attack, because closer squares would not be the nearest.

Comment: Well yeah, of course. It doesn't actually say to stop there though. It just says that you must move to that spot. So I was moving to that stop, and then moving one closer. Seemed so natural I didn't even think about it.